# Is there any way to warn user when file changes all the time and can't be uploaded to the web?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, file-upload

When file keeps changing in the underlying filesystem of the user, Chrome (and possibly other browsers) are throwing nasty ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED error for the user to wonder about.

(on Chrome, thanks to this quite justified check:

```
  if (!expected_modification_time_.is_null() &&
      (expected_modification_time_ - file_info_.last_modified)
              .magnitude()
              .InSeconds() != 0) {
    return ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED;
  }
```

)

The question however is, how to make a more user friendly message for the user that "Sorry, you can't upload file xyz because it keeps changing all the time"?

To reproduce the behavior, try to upload file from Unix-like system while `watch -n 0.5 touch -m your-file.jpg` command is active (and file is big enough operation lasts longer than half a second)

(Side-question is why the file keeps being modified, but it's for another time. I'd said it's highly suspicious)

This maybe more general question to [Prevent HTML file input from selecting files in Google Drive while using Android's native file chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516930/prevent-html-file-input-from-selecting-files-in-google-drive-while-using-android)

Comment: I have just encountered this problem.  In my use case the check does not seem justified although I can see why it could be in other situations.  My app allows the user to select a file and then upload.  That file is parsed by the server if there is an error, the user could previously fix the error and press upload again.  Now they have to first reselect the file which is a poorer UX.