# upload file cause the error "net::ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED"

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

[image]

I am using C#.net Core for the back-end API and angular 6 for the front-end. When I upload a file to test on my localhost, when i try upload, it always give me error "net::ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED" for some reason, but after a maybe one minute or two, then i try upload again. the error is gone and file successful upload, i try another test, it keep happening, and always after few minutes, then error gone and file can be upload, why does the first time when i try to upload it give me "net::ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED".

Can someone help me on this, thank you so much

Comment: I might be late to the party, but this is an open issue for Chromium, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916331/re-uploading-a-file-with-ajax-after-it-was-changed-causes-neterr-upload-file-c. You might want to try Firefox for this.

Answer (score 3):

You will get this error if you:

- Select a file in the upload box
- Change the file on your computer
- Then try to upload the file

Chrome is telling you that it won't send a request to the server (400 bad request) because the contents of the file has changed.

This is by design because it is a security risk for the user to select a file and then some other process to change it before uploading.

You can refresh the page or clear the contents of the upload box to clear it. That means the user will need to reselect the file but that's what you want from a security perspective.