# How to solve blob url when deploy site from local host to another host (netlify)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, file-upload

i want to know that is there any method to solve blob url problem. Actully i take input as type file(image) and then i preview that image to user which he/she uploaded. so for this i make  objurl of that input image as  shown in attached screen shot and then i used that url in img tag as src attritube. this works best when i run my react app in localhost but when i deploy my site on netlify its not working. the consol error is also attached. if anyone know about it would be grateful.

[image]

[image: image Error]

Comment: Can't see the error image both look the same

Comment: am sorry. now it visible. please look at it and let me know if you can solve it

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916331/re-uploading-a-file-with-ajax-after-it-was-changed-causes-neterr-upload-file-c)