# Uploading file triggers the "Unknown Error" caused by ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED

Tags: javascript, angular, download

I am using C# ASP.NET Web API for the back-end API and angular 16 for the front-end. When I upload a file to my localhost controller, all is good until I change the content of the file. When I do that I am getting an error "Unknown Error", but it is caused by "net::ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED" - that what my Chrome console window displays.
Why am I not getting simply some exception that would clearly spell out what the problem is (stating that file has changed) instead of reporting "Unknown Error" which is pretty much useless.
This is what my Chrome console displays:
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916331/re-uploading-a-file-with-ajax-after-it-was-changed-causes-neterr-upload-file-c

Comment: It has no reference to an "Unknown Error" and that is my issue